# How do I setup routing for react in GAE? Directly routing to react-router-dom routes via URL fails in GAE on basic create-react-app?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, react-router, create-react-app, app.yaml

### **ANSWER for now**

This was tough for me to get exactly right.  Very little in the way of guidance via Google.  I hope this helps others.

As Dan Cornilescu pointed out, the handlers accept the first match.  So we go from more specific to less specific.  I've solved this by following the folder structure created by `npm run build`:
1. Handle sub-directories for js, css, and media.
2. Handle json and ico requests for manifest.json and fav.ico.
3. Route all other traffic to index.html.

```
handlers:
  - url: /static/js/(.*)
    static_files: build/static/js/\1
    upload: build/static/js/(.*)
  - url: /static/css/(.*)
    static_files: build/static/css/\1
    upload: build/static/css/(.*)
  - url: /static/media/(.*)
    static_files: build/static/media/\1
    upload: build/static/media/(.*)
  - url: /(.*\.(json|ico))$
    static_files: build/\1
    upload: build/.*\.(json|ico)$
  - url: /
    static_files: build/index.html
    upload: build/index.html
  - url: /.*
    static_files: build/index.html
    upload: build/index.html
```

More efficient answers welcome.

> **Original Question:**
>
> ### Setting GAE app.yaml for react-router routes produces "Unexpected token <" errors.

In the development enviroment, all routes work when called directly.  localhost:5000 and localhost:5000/test produce expected results.

In GAE standard app.yaml functions for the root directory when the URL www.test-app.com is called directly.  **www.test-app.com/test produces a 404 error.**

```
app.yaml #1

runtime: nodejs8
instance_class: F1
automatic_scaling:
  max_instances: 1

handlers:
  - url: /
    static_files: build/index.html
    upload: build/index.html
```

Configuring app.yaml to accept wildcard routes fails for all paths.  www.test-app.com/ and www.test-app.com/test produce an error "Unexpected token <".  It appears that it is serving .js files as index.html.

```
app.yaml #2

runtime: nodejs8
instance_class: F1
automatic_scaling:
  max_instances: 1

handlers:
  - url: /.*
    static_files: build/index.html
    upload: build/index.html
```

## Steps to reproduce this issue:

Node: 10.15.0
npm: 6.4.1

`gcloud init` via Google Cloud SDK

`npm init react-app test-app`

`npm install react-router-dom`

Add router to index.js:

```
index.js

import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';


ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <App />
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root'));
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Add routing to app.js:

```
app.js

import {Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Route exact path="/"
          render={() =>  <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
              <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
              <p>
                Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
              </p>
              <a
                className="App-link"
                href="https://reactjs.org"
                target="_blank"
                rel="noopener noreferrer"
              >
                Learn React
              </a>
            </header>
          </div>} />
        <Route exact path="/test"
          render={() =>  <div className="App">
            Hello, World!
          </div>} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

No changes to package.json:

```
package.json

{
  "name": "test-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

`npm run build`

`gcloud app deploy`

### How do we convince app engine to allow a react SPA to process routes directly?

Comment: At the runtime it says it's nodejs8 does that mean the nodejs that loads its react index.html?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge that is correct.  node.js is serving react via index.html.

Comment: Yes I just checked in doc in GAE, so to spa / react the nodejs have to load the file with the route set to point all to index.html Ex `router.get('/*', (req, res) => { res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../../build', 'index.html')) }); ` . Now how to set this in your GAE settings I no longer know, in my deploys with nodejs and reactjs I always set this manually.

Comment: Thank you.  And this is similar to the responses I've found around.  But I don't know where this code goes.  That looks to me like server-side code, like express.  

This is a point of confusion for me.  I have a service that runs express, but my react content is not served from there.

Comment: Yes I understand, reading the doc from GEA seems to me that it will be this, nodejs runs an express and loads its index.html, the point is to change the configuration inside the server.

Comment: The yaml appears to be what handles this from what I can see.  So at this time we're back to churning through different yaml settings to try and force this to work.

Comment: @NathanShepherd I love you I love you I love you. There are two things to note about this question: 1) It contains an answer! An amazing answer! (The handlers in the very first code block, for those who skimmed it like me.) 2) People should refine it carefully based on what kind of files end up in their build directory (for example, I had an images folder and some different file types that I added in). I was stuck on this problem for hours before I found this.

Answer (score 26):

I took the answers from [Nathan Shephard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5463417/nathan-shepherd) and [Dan Cornilescu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4495081/dan-cornilescu) and condensed them into the app.yaml below.  It seems to be working for my React SPA on GAE Standard.  No application server (ex: serve.js, ExpressJS, etc) is necessary.

```
env: standard
runtime: nodejs10
service: default

handlers:
  - url: /static
    static_dir: build/static

  - url: /(.*\.(json|ico|js))$
    static_files: build/\1
    upload: build/.*\.(json|ico|js)$

  - url: .*
    static_files: build/index.html
    upload: build/index.html
```

Comment: Perfect example!

Comment: Works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

When a request comes in its URL path is compared against the patterns specified in the `handlers` section of the `app.yaml` file, in the order in which they are specified. The first match wins and whatever the matching handler specifies is executed. Once you grasp this there's no more need to guess what's going on.

So you're making requests to `www.test-app.com` and `www.test-app.com/test`, which translate to the `/` and `/test` URL paths, respectively.

With your 1st `app.yaml` (note that your patterns are identical in it, the 2nd one will never be matched):

- `/` matches the 1st pattern, the static `build/index.html` from your app directory (not a .js file!) will be returned
- `/test` doesn't match any pattern, 404 will be returned

With your 2nd `app.yaml`:

- `/` matches the 2nd pattern, the static `build` dir will be served (which I presume triggers your node app, but I'm not certain - I'm not a node user)
- `/test` matches the 1st pattern, again that static `build/index.html` file will be returned

I suspect the `build/index.html` file from your app directory from where you made your deployment (that entire `build` dir was uploaded as a static dir)  had HTML syntax errors at the time when you made the deployment (that's how it was frozen - it's static), causing the error message you see.

You *might* have fixed the local copy of the file since the deployment, which could explain why it appears to be working locally now. If so a re-deployment of the app should fix the problems on GAE as well.

UPDATE:

I don't think you'd want a *static* handler for your `build/index.html` - it'll always serve whatever content was in that file in your local workspace at deployment time.

I'd follow the *non-static* example from the official [app.yaml Configuration File](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref#handlers_element) (updated with a `.*` pattern instead of the `/.*` original one to be certain it matches `/` as well):

```
handlers:
- url: .*
  script: auto
```

It might even be possible to drop the `handlers` section altogether, I don't see one in several [Node.js samples repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples) examples:

- [appengine/datastore/app.standard.yaml](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/datastore/app.standard.yaml)
- [appengine/memcached/app.standard.yaml](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/memcached/app.standard.yaml)
- [appengine/storage/standard/app.yaml](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/storage/standard/app.yaml)

Comment: I have updated the app.yaml files in the main post based on what I gleaned from your answer.

All paths, I believe, are intended to go to the same place.  Since it is a single page application with routing, all paths go to the same build/index.html.

When the pattern is / it works just fine.  When the pattern is /.* it should match everything and produce the same result?  But it isn't so there lies my confusion.

Comment: I'm not sure `/.*` matches `/`. I'd just use `.*` instead, it does match `/`.

Answer (score 1):

I spent some time on this and this works perfectly for my React CRA on GAE Standard.

```
runtime: nodejs10
service: bbi-staging
env: standard
instance_class: F2
handlers:
  - url: /(.*\.(gif|media|json|ico|eot|ttf|woff|woff2|png|jpg|css|js))$
    static_files: build/\1
    upload: build/(.*)
  - url: /(.*)
    static_files: build/index.html
    upload: build/index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

After spending 1 splendid day enjoying with Google App Engine, webpack and app.yaml, here is the configuration that worked for me:

**webpack.js** (only the json parts that are relevant, i.e. module's rules):

```
  {
    test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
    use: [
    {
      loader: 'url-loader',
      options: {
        name: '[name].[ext]',
        outputPath: 'media/',
        limit: 8192
      }
    }
    ]
  },
  {
    test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
    use: [
    {
      loader: 'file-loader',
      options: {
        name: '[name].[ext]',
        outputPath: 'fonts/'
      }
    }
    ]
  },
```

**app.yaml**

```
runtime: nodejs10 
handlers:
  - url: /(.*\.(png|ico|jpg|gif))$
    static_files: dist/\1
    upload: dist/.*\.(png|ico|jpg|gif)$
  - url: /fonts/(.*\.(woff|woff2))$
    static_files: dist/fonts/\1
    upload: dist/fonts/.*\.(woff|woff2)$
  - url: /html.js
    static_files: dist/html.js
    upload: dist/html.js
  - url: /javascript.js
    static_files: dist/javascript.js
    upload: dist/javascript.js
  - url: /.*
    static_files: dist/index.html
    upload: dist/index.html
    secure: always
    redirect_http_response_code: 301
  - url: /
    static_dir: dist
```

*Note: my output directory is dist, so make sure you change it to build if that is the case for you*

Answer (score 0):

For me worked great following setup:

```
runtime: nodejs16
service: development

handlers:
  - url: /static
    secure: always
    static_dir: build/static

  - url: /(.*\.(gif|media|json|ico|eot|ttf|woff|woff2|png|jpg|css|js|svg))$
    secure: always
    static_files: build/\1
    upload: build/.*\.(gif|media|json|ico|eot|ttf|woff|woff2|png|jpg|css|js|svg)$

  - url: .*
    secure: always
    static_files: build/index.html
    upload: build/index.html
```