# Deploy create-react-app on Google App Engine

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, create-react-app

I'm trying to deploy my app created using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) on Google App Engine.

My app works well on local (both `npm start` and `npm run build & serve -s build`).
However, the deployed app on Google App Engine shows only the index.html, and does not call my react code.

The Chrome Developer Console is showing `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`.

Also, I found on console.cloud.google.com that the deployed app did not include the build folder. Is this correct?

Anyone can solve this problem?

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "XXXXX",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.2",
    "react-ga": "^2.5.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
 },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

Also, here is my app.yaml.

```
runtime: nodejs10

handlers:
- url: /.*
  static_files: build/index.html
  upload: build/index.html
- url: /
  static_dir: build
```

Comment: Did you do npm run build before deploying ?

Comment: I did, but not worked...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As a result of searching the web many times, I found that the routing system of my react app was the cause.

As [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54247953/how-do-i-setup-routing-for-react-in-gae-directly-routing-to-react-router-dom-ro) states, we need to be careful about authoring app.yaml.
If we write the following item first, GAE returns `build/index.html` for all queries, including access to `/static/js` and `/static/css`.

```
- url: /
  static_files: build/index.html
  upload: build/index.html
```

`create-react-app` creates a build folder and static subfolders for `npm run build`.
Thus, I had to write my app.yaml more specific like this:

```
handlers:
  - url: /static/js/(.*)
    static_files: build/static/js/\1
    upload: build/static/js/(.*)
  - url: /static/css/(.*)
    static_files: build/static/css/\1
    upload: build/static/css/(.*)
  - url: /static/media/(.*)
    static_files: build/static/media/\1
    upload: build/static/media/(.*)
  - url: /(.*\.(json|ico))$
    static_files: build/\1
    upload: build/.*\.(json|ico)$
  - url: /
    static_files: build/index.html
    upload: build/index.html
  - url: /.*
    static_files: build/index.html
    upload: build/index.html
```

Comment: Please edit the answer putting the complete app.yaml. what did you put in runtime?

Answer (score 7):

Can you check this document - https://medium.com/tech-tajawal/deploying-react-app-to-google-app-engine-a6ea0d5af132

This will help you. I have deployed my app using same steps.

sample yaml file

```
    runtime: python27
    api_version: 1
    threadsafe: true
    handlers:
    - url: /
      static_files: build/index.html
      upload: build/index.html
    - url: /
      static_dir: build
```

Reference link - https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-deploy-a-static-react-site-to-google-cloud-platform-55ff0bd0f509

Thank you!

Comment: @Daisuke SHIBATO - Added .yaml file and reference link for making things clear.

Comment: Hi Harsh, thanks for your comment. I found that the cause of this problem was my routing of the react app on GAE.

Comment: Glad your problem was solved. Please accept this answer if it helped you so that others having a similar issue can find this helpful too.

Comment: Tries to upload all the node_modules as well?

Comment: No it shouldn't