# Deploy create-react-app-typescript on Google App Engine

Tags: reactjs, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, create-react-app

I am triying to deploy an application created using CRA with Typescript into the Google Cloud App Engine service, however, for some reason, the appspot link keeps loading forever until a 502 Bad Gateway appears (the error appears sometimes, normally it just keeps loading..)

I've already checked several tutorials and questions without success.

- [Deploy create-react-app on Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54820986/deploy-create-react-app-on-google-app-engine)
- https://medium.com/tech-tajawal/deploying-react-app-to-google-app-engine-a6ea0d5af132

The app.yaml is the following:

```html
env: flex
runtime: nodejs
handlers:
  - url: /static/js/(.*)
    static_files: build/static/js/\1
    upload: build/static/js/(.*)
  - url: /static/css/(.*)
    static_files: build/static/css/\1
    upload: build/static/css/(.*)
  - url: /static/media/(.*)
    static_files: build/static/media/\1
    upload: build/static/media/(.*)
  - url: /(.*\.(json|ico))$
    static_files: build/\1
    upload: build/.*\.(json|ico)$
  - url: /
    static_files: build/index.html
    upload: build/index.html
  - url: /.*
    static_files: build/index.html
    upload: build/index.html
env_variables:
  REACT_APP_DEV_API_URL: "......"
  REACT_APP_MAP_API_KEY: "........"
# [END app_yaml]
```

[Logs of the app engine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wo0Vi.png) (It seems it's calling the 'npm run start' command each time I open a page)

Of course, my application works fine in dev mode and also it doesn't seem to be any problem in the [deployment logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2yZg.png).
If someone has experienced this problem before, please let me know how to solve it. Thanks in advance.

package.json:

```
{
 "name": "testing-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "@types/google-map-react": "^1.1.5",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.149",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-helmet": "^5.0.15",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.3",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/swiper": "^5.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "google-map-react": "^1.1.6",
    "lodash.differenceby": "^4.8.0",
    "lodash.throttle": "^4.1.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-circular-progressbar": "^2.0.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-id-swiper": "^3.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.3.0",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.88.2",
    "styled-components": "^5.0.1",
    "swiper": "^5.3.6",
    "typescript": "~3.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.14.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.14.0",
    "cross-env": "^6.0.3",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.0.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^14.0.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.9.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^5.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.19.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.17.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^2.3.0",
    "gh-pages": "^2.2.0",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "lint-staged": "^9.5.0",
    "pre-commit": "^1.2.2",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.js": [
      "npm run lint:eslint:fix",
      "git add --force"
    ],
    "*.json": [
      "prettier --write",
      "git add --force"
    ]
  },
  "pre-commit": "lint:staged",
  "resolutions": {
    "serialize-javascript": "^2.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "build:clean": "rimraf ./build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint:staged": "lint-staged",
    "lint:eslint": "eslint --ignore-path .gitignore",
    "lint:eslint:fix": "eslint --ignore-path .gitignore --fix",
    "prettify": "prettier --write"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

The project structure is the [typical CRA with containers-components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6khJ.png) (Ignore the nginx.conf and dockerfile which I was using for testing another way with Gcloud run at the time of the photo)

**Edit:** Added project structure and package.json

Comment: Could you please share your Dockerfile? thanks

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I am not deploying it with a dockerfile. As indicated in the tutorials, I just use *gcloud app run deploy* . I've seen another method with Gcloud run which uses it, but I was wondering why it didn't work with App Engine.

Comment: Could you please share your package.json file? Otherwise could you please share the structure of your app files? Thanks

Comment: By the [App Engine Flexible Official Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/quickstart#deploy_and_run_hello_world_on_app_engine) , you have to use gcloud app delpoy command, could you please explain why are you running gcloud app run deploy command?

Comment: Ah sorry I didn't explain clearly. I was talking about that command (gcloud app deploy). I will update the package.json and structure later today.  Thanks

Comment: @NibrassH added the project structure and package.json.

Comment: When you deploy do you get any errors in Cloud Shell? In case yes, could you please rerun as following : gcloud app deploy --verbosity=debug? Please also check the Stackdriver Logging for your service in App Engine after deploying or redeploying it and share it please. Thanks a lot for providing package.json as it seems to does not have any issues

Comment: Please check [this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38021633/8791788) also.

Comment: Thank you . I will write back after testing those.

Comment: Hello @NibrassH I solved my problem by changing the App.yaml from node to custom and adding a Dockerfile with its respective nginx.conf (according to the settings of this tutorial https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/deploy-react-nginx-cloud-run) . I tried the above but there was no error neither on logging or deployment, it was just keep loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved (May 18, 2020)**
I changed my approach and go for a custom runtime and it worked out. 
Here is the configuration I used if anyone encounter this problem in the future.

Change the runtime to custom in the App.yaml

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
env: flex
runtime: custom
```

And include a Dockerfile with a nginx.conf for the runtime management

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM node:8-alpine as react-build
WORKDIR /app
COPY . ./
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

# server environment
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/configfile.template
ENV PORT 8080
ENV HOST 0.0.0.0
RUN sh -c "envsubst '\$PORT'  < /etc/nginx/conf.d/configfile.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf"
COPY --from=react-build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

**nginx.conf**

```
    server {
     listen       $PORT;
     server_name  localhost;

     location / {
         root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
         index  index.html index.htm;
         try_files $uri /index.html;
     }

     gzip on;
     gzip_vary on;
     gzip_min_length 10240;
     gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
     gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml text/javascript application/x-javascript application/xml;
     gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";

}
```

This configuration appears in one of the tutorials here: https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/deploy-react-nginx-cloud-run

Thank you to @Nibrass H for suggesting some possible solutions.

Comment: thanks for letting me know that you solved your issue. Please let me know in case you have any further questions regarding this issue.

Comment: I was curious about why the default Node runtime was failing , but I will check that out in depth later. Thank you very much!

Comment: Could you please try to follow this [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/quickstart) and let me know if you are still seeing the 502 BAD Gateway error to narrow down the issue.

Comment: I tried to run it on local but it keeps loading , no errors or anything, but the "hello world" message never appears. It seems there is a problem with the tutorial https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/issues/1757 (I'm on Mac though). Did you have any problems running it locally?

Comment: I was able to run it locally, and it appears hello world on the web preview. In the Github issue, there are some workaround, do you follow them and were you able to run it correctly? Otherwise could you please update the post with the detailed steps when running it locally and in App Engine? Thanks

Comment: I will check it out carefully on the weekend and update my findings here. Thanks!

Comment: I got pretty busy and finally was able to test it properly. No problems whatsoever. Thanks .