# why {app-url}/reset-password/{token} url showing page not found in react app deployed on google cloud where it working in local?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-platform, react-router, react-router-dom

**Token:**  {app-url}/reset-password/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE2MTI3OTUxNjksInVzZXJJZCI6NjB9.YS1seObMs45hcTDH4nSbTNh1W4fTTqPcpF4TUamfFFk

**Error:** Error: Not Found
The requested URL /reset-password/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE2MTI3OTUxNjksInVzZXJJZCI6NjB9.YS1seObMs45hcTDH4nSbTNh1W4fTTqPcpF4TUamfFFk was not found on this server.

**Code:**

```
<Route exact path="/reset-password/:token" component={ResetPassword} />
```

[image]

Does this issue bcs app deployed in GCloud or any thing needs to change in react code (project is create react app not webpack) ?

**app.yaml**

```
runtime: nodejs12
handlers:
- url: /(.*\..+)$
  static_files: build/\1
  upload: build/(.*\..+)$
- url: /.*
  static_files: build/index.html
  upload: build/index.html
```

Answer (score 2):

Needs to change app.yaml

```
runtime: nodejs12
handlers:
  - url: /static
    static_dir: build/static
  - url: /(.*\.(json|ico|js|png))$
    static_files: build/\1
    upload: build/.*\.(json|ico|js|png)$
  - url: .*
    static_files: build/index.html
    upload: build/index.html
```

thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/55831186